# Grails data binding does not work OOTB for a date type with BindingFormat

Tags: grails, data-binding, grails-2.3

I have a date attribute `deactivation` in my domain class called `Service`:

```
import org.grails.databinding.BindingFormat
class Service
    // ...
    @BindingFormat('dd-MM-yyyy')
    Date deactivation
```

I'm using jquery UI datepicker to grab a date from the user, using custom format:

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: serviceInstance, field: 'deactivation', 'error')} ">
    <g:textField id="deactivation" name="deactivation" value="${serviceInstance?.deactivation}"/>
</div>

<script>    
$(function() {
    $('#deactivation').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
});
</script>
```

With the standard controller update method:

```
@Transactional
def update(Service serviceInstance) {
    // ...
```

And this does not work - `deactivation` attribute is null after submitting the form. However, when I add this line at the beginning of update() method:

```
serviceInstance.deactivation = params.date('deactivation', 'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

It's all fine, and `deactivation` attribute is set with correct value.

What did I miss?

**EDIT:**

I made some further experiments by adding following piece of code:

```
    def update(Provpn serviceInstance) {
        def instance = new Provpn(params)
        def instance2 = new Provpn()
        def instance3 = new Provpn()
        bindData(instance2, params)
        bindData(instance3, params, [include: ['deactivation']])
```

With help of the debugger i've found out that only `instance3` has the `deactivation` attribute set correctly (the one made using `bindData()` and `include` option). Other 2 instances have `deactivation` set to null. I wonder if this issue might be based on naming?

Comment: Inspect serviceInstance.errors and see what is there.

Comment: hasErrors() returns false, I also debugged the serviceInstance and errors list is empty.

Comment: If you can recreate in a sample app, attach it to a Grails JIRA. I am sure this is something simple.

Comment: If you are using the spring binder this annotation is not supposed to work. Are you using the spring binder?

Comment: I have added following line: 
grails.databinding.useSpringBinder = false
To Config file to make sure i'm not using it, but it's still the same. However, i've created a new project, and tried to recreate the issue, but without effect - so it seems that it's about this particular project configuration. I made this project using grails 2.3.4, and then upgraded it to 2.3.7, but I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: Actually after fully cleaning and rebuilding the project problem disappeared - and it works even without setting grails.databinding.useSpringBinder to false...

Comment: Ok.  You shouldn't need to set useSpringBinder to false.  There is no reason to ever do that.  It needs to be set to true in order to use the Spring binder, but there isn't really any reason to set it to false unless you just want to be explicit.  false is the default value.